# "It is worth mentioning" versus "it is worth to mention"

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

What’s the right way to use the phrase *it is worth*? Which of the following two approaches is right, and how they are different?

1. It is worth **mentioning** that [. . .]
2. It is worth **to mention** that [. . .]

Comment: _Worth_ can take a gerund complement, but not an infinitive complement. Hence (1) is OK, but (2) isn't.

Comment: However, _worth it_ **can** take an infinitive complement. _It's worth it to consider the price carefully before you commit yourself_ But not **It's worth to consider the price carefully before you commit yourself*.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first example, "it is worth mentioning that", is acceptable.  The second, "it is worth to mention that", is incorrect.  One might correct it by saying:

> It is worth it to mention that...

Though this is a very awkward construction.  A better version might be:

> It is worth*while* to mention that...

As to *why* these particular constructions are acceptable and the others are not, I admit that I'm having a hard time figuring that out myself.  I'm not even completely sure what part of speech "worth" is in each of those phrases.